# jetty diplays the code of jsp files

Tags: jsp

I am trying to deploy my web application with jetty, but jetty diplays the code of jsp files at the adress: http://localhost:8080/index.jsp
has this a relation to my browser?or is it a problem of jetty?
Could someone help me!
thanks

Comment: Could you explain what is the code of jsp files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the jsp and jsp-api jars. Otherwise jetty is unable to render jsp pages.

Comment: thank you for replying, in fact jetty I use is embedded in an osgi container and I use all the necessary bundles!!
in your opinion could this be related to my browser
Thanks

Comment: If you see the source code of your jsp this is a server issue.